# Excel MATCH can't find cell value but can find fixed value

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match, excel-2010, lookup

I'm working on an excel 2010 workbook that uses a series of tables to generate calculations for me. One such calculation *was* working up until a change I made last evening on a completely unrelated table, and I can't get it working again.

**TL;DR**:

- `Table_ChallengeCalc` columns `Easy`, `Medium`, `Hard`, `Deadly`, `None` need to show the corresponding values from `Table_Difficulty` of the same name, matching the `Table_ChallengeCalc[Level]` value for the assigned player with the matching `Table_Difficulty[Level]` reference in `Table_Difficulty`.
- The columns match until `Table_ChallengeCalc[Level] >= 9`, then just start randomly assigning values, if not just `#N/A`, to all players on the table.
- `LOOKUP`, `VLOOKUP`, and nested
  `INDEX/MATCH` have not been successful so far.

---

Here's what I'm working with: 
[image: Faux Working]

For the sake of explanation, we'll focus on the `Easy` column under the `Challenge Calculations` table, which is coded as `Table_ChallengeCalc`. First, the formula running in cell `M4`:

> =IFERROR(LOOKUP(L4,[Level],Table_Difficulty[Easy]),0)

What this is supposed to do is look at the value in the cell immediately to its left (`L4`), find the corresponding value on the `Difficulty Chart` (`Table_Difficulty`), and display the experience value for that level. In this case, it should be referencing "level 7" on the difficulty chart, and returning the value "350". This *appears* to be working at first, but if even one of the players' levels hit level 9 or above ...

[image: Table Breaking]

... every single player shows 350 as their point value under the `Easy` column, except the level 9 player. Furthermore, if I put any player at level 20, it just outright returns 0 (if I remove the `IFERROR`, it just shows `#N/A`).

[image: LV20 Breaking]

If I replace `[Level]` in the formula with `Table_Difficulty[Level]`, all cells under `Easy` return #N/A regardless of player level.

I really have no idea what broke, and I'd like to get that fixed. However, I did also consider the possibility that it's because I'm using arrays. Experimenting from there, I get the same results if I use a `VLOOKUP` formula, so I scratched that, and then tried a nested `INDEX/MATCH` and can't get that to work either. If the LOOKUP isn't going to work, I figure this would be the ideal alternative anyway.

Focusing on the `MATCH` formula for the time being:

> =MATCH(L4,Table_Difficulty[Level],0)

The above formula results in `#N/A`. However, if I replace `L4` in the formula with just `7`, like so ...

> =MATCH(7,Table_Difficulty[Level],0)

... It returns with the correct row on `Table_Difficulty` (7). As great as this is, I need it to be able to accept a variable value that may change later (as the players level up), so this isn't an option.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**: So with some help, we discovered that for some reason `L4` isn't seeing itself as `7`, but instead `"7"`. By using `=L4=7` we get a `FALSE`, the same if we do `=L4=B10`. *However*, if we do `=L4="7"`, the result returns `TRUE`. I have no idea how to address this yet, but it's something I guess.

Comment: if instead of `Table_Difficulty[Level]`, your select manually the range, does it work?

Comment: No, same results.

Comment: And if you call L4 as sheet_name!L4 ?

Comment: Yup, same thing

Comment: This is really weird, I have never heard of it behaving this way. Maybe there's a hidden char in the level column, try erasing it and rewriting it?

Comment: I tried that, didn't seem to make a difference. I even tried using TRIM to make sure there's nothing extra in there, and no change

Comment: `=(L4=7)` ? `=(L4=B10)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166920/discussion-between-damiano-and-liora-haydont).

Answer (score 0):

> **EDIT:** So with some help, we discovered that for some reason L4 isn't
>   seeing itself as 7, but instead "7". By using =L4=7 we get a FALSE,
>   the same if we do =L4=B10. However, if we do =L4="7", the result
>   returns TRUE. I have no idea how to address this yet, but it's
>   something I guess.

With this in mind you have a couple of approaches you can take. You could look at ensuring that the source data is in number format, add some validation to the formula forcing a number format or ignore the lookup in place of a fixed `INDEX()` providing the table is going to remain static as displayed.

In terms of validation in the formula itself, you would look at calculating numerics with the value, most commonly subtracting 0 or multiplying by 1:

`=MATCH(L4-0,Table_Difficulty[Level],0)` / `=MATCH(L4*1,Table_Difficulty[Level],0)`

This should handle fine as long as the string can be converted to a number.

For the `INDEX()` method, as the table is static, you know that Level 1 is the 1st indexed row so you wouldn't need to use `MATCH()` at all as the level will be the row you want returned:

`=INDEX(Table_Difficulty[Easy],L4)` (or `,L4-0)` if an error is thrown due to data type)